# Limit ImageWMS request size

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wms

Is there any built-in way of limiting the request width/height of ImageWMS sources and have the map just scale the image up to fill the extent? I'm building an application that includes a bunch of WMS providers that don't support resolutions higher than 2048.

Comment: it depends on the client application you are using - but try using tiles to avoid these issues.

Comment: You want to reduce or increase this value? There is a limit to all the wms max tile size. For e.g. MS4W supports max 2048 pixels tile size. Which WMS server you are using?

Comment: I want (if possible), for ex. if OpenLayers tries to request a 3000x1000 image, request a 2048x1000 image instead and stretch it. Maybe I could draw it into a canvas first and then set the Image src. I think our end-client would rather have a blurry image than loading the map with tiles (which would be the best solution, I know.) I could also create a tile grid with 2048px sized tiles, but I'd have to recreate it every time the projection changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 - Stretch**

1. Custom loader
2. If the image is larger than 2048px, store
   `originalWidth` and `originalHeight` and request image with
   `min(2048, original[Width|Height])`.
3. Draw requested image
   into a canvas with size `(originalWidth, originalHeight)`
4. Set canvas data as src for `Image`

**Solution 2 - Tile**

1. Use TileWMS with a tile grid of 2048px sized tiles
2. Recreate source and tile grid everytime projection changes